# Partial derivatives at the origin in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

> Given a function $f(x,y)$, I would like to better understand the way the partial derivatives $ f_r(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta)) $ and
> $f_\theta(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$ are defined at the origin. In addition, at what conditions do these partial derivatives exist, and what exactly they represent.

To do so, I tried denoting $F(r,\theta) = f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$ and then to write the definition of the partial derivatives $F_r,F_\theta$ for $r=0$, but had no idea how to proceed. I am not even sure if the following expressions are correct,$$F_r(0,\theta) = \lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{F(0+h,\theta) - F(0,\theta) }{h }$$$$F_\theta(0,\theta) = \lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{F(0,\theta+h) - F(0,\theta) }{h }$$

> Are those correct and correspond to the definition of the partial
> derivatives $F_r$ and $F_\theta$ at the origin?

In general, since $z=0$ correspond to only one value of r, but many of theta, what is the interpretation for $F_\theta(0,\theta) $ ?

> As an example, if we consider  $$ f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{(x+y)^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\ 0,\text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ can we use polar coordinates and the definition of the
> partial derivatives w.r.t them in order to determine whether or not
> this function is differentiable at the  origin?

My questions are still left unanswered, even after going over the following:
[Partial derivatives at the origin post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083818/how-do-derivatives-w-r-to-polar-variables-behave-at-the-origin)

Thank you

Comment: @PaulFrost :: Fixed. Thanks